# How to use while-no-input?

Tags: elisp, elisp-macros

From the docstring:

> Execute BODY only as long as there's no pending input.
>   If input arrives, that ends the execution of BODY,
>   and `while-no-input` returns t.  Quitting makes it return nil.
>   If BODY finishes, `while-no-input` returns whatever value BODY produced.

If I understand correctly, this macro allows me to (attempt to)
perform a heavy computation without hanging the interface. That's
certainly a concept that I find attractive, but I'm left wondering
when is that useful in practice.

It seems that the computation can be interrupted at any moment, with
no information on where that happened, and no easy way of resuming it
later. Which makes me think it might not be that useful after all...

- Is there a recommended way of using the `while-no-input` macro?
- Are there any example usages of this macro in the wild?

Comment: [Looks like](https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=extension%3Ael++while-no-input&ref=searchresults&s=indexed&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) icomplete+, ivy, helm are few of the packages using it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Indeed, there is no support for resumption.  Of course, the body of `while-no-input` can do regular "checkpoints" so as to know where to start next time.

But the original motivation for this functionality was in cases where the computed information is likely useless after the next command.  More specifically, it was introduced for `icomplete`, so that the computation of the set of completion candidates does not prevent the user from typing further text (which in turn requires recomputation of that set of completion candidates anyway).

Answer (score 4):

It's super-useful in [counsel-git-grep](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/blob/master/counsel.el): I'm able to call `git grep` on the whole 3,800,000 lines of the Emacs git repository **after each** key stroke. No hangups.
And it's OK to be interrupted, you just need to check for that.

Answer (score 0):

My library [asyncloop](https://github.com/meedstrom/asyncloop) can be considered an abstraction over `while-no-input`. It provides automatic resumption as well as manual pause/resume.

I also explain how you can use `while-no-input` yourself without a library, in the README there.